# How to remove these non existing files from Git?

Tags: git

MS Word did create these files automatically while the files were opened. I accidentially committed these files. After closing MS Word the files have been deleted automatically. Now Git still shows the files and I cannot remove, add or checkout them. How to remove these files from the repository?

```sh
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  
    deleted:    NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~$VFX.docx
    deleted:    NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~$ceSceneLighting.docx
    modified:   NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~$ceSceneSetup.docx
        
        
        
$ git checkout NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~$VFX.docx
error: pathspec 'NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~.docx' did not match any file(s) known to git

$ git rm --cached NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~$VFX.docx
fatal: pathspec 'NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~.docx' did not match any files

$ git rm NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~$VFX.docx
fatal: pathspec 'NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~.docx' did not match any files
```

Comment: Try `git add 'NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~$VFX.docx'`?

Comment: That worked! I always tried to use "" instead of ''. I thought it's equivalent... Anyway thank you so much.

Comment: @MasterMax the tilde `~` was likely being interpreted as your home directory. Try `cd ~` or `cd ~/Documents`.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, when you use a variable in a command it is prefixed with a `$`. Therefore, when you type:

```
git rm NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~$VFX.docx
```

Bash tries to replace `$VFX` with a variable `VFX`. When it isn't found, empty string is used instead, as you can see in the error message:

```
fatal: pathspec 'NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~.docx' did not match any files
```

Note that `$VFX` has disappeared.

The solution is to quote the path with single quotes, which prevents variable substitution:

```
git rm 'NonProject/GameObjectSetupInstructions/RaceScene/~$VFX.docx'
```

Comment: Doesn't the replacement happen when using double-quotes too?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: for bash, yes. Different shells have different rules, so it can get messy, but that's why the single quotes worked.

Comment: I tried double quotes first and it did not work in my Git shell. Single quotes worked.